# My formulary is not working .... asp.net mvc 4 razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I already tried a lot of changes and nothing worked.... I am having compiler errors...
The object of the formularys is that the user will give the place a rating using radio button and will write a text review inside TextArea....

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

Rating:
for(int i=1;i<6;i++){
<text>@i</text>
Html.RadioButton("Rating",i)
}


<h2>Write a Review for @Model.Name</h2>
Html.TextArea("Review")


<input type="submit" value="Send Review" />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with how you're trying to print html inside the `@using` block. Try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @:Rating:
  for(int i=1;i<6;i++) {
    <text>@i</text>
    @Html.RadioButton("Rating",i)
  }

  <h2>Write a Review for @Model.Name</h2>
  @Html.TextArea("Review")

  <input type="submit" value="Send Review" />
}
```

Or better yet, replace `@:Rating:` with

```
@Html.Label("Rating", "Rating:")
```